# Help me find an example of this sequence!

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

one of the examples in my book defines a sequence $s_n = f(s_{n-1})$ for $n \ge 1$. We select $s_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $s_1 = f(s_0)$ and $s_2 = f(s_1)$ and so forth.

I know for this problem we can just define it without providing a set function; however, I'm just curious if you guys know how to define such a sequence. I've been thinking of possible sequences that satisfy this recursive definition but I can't come up with any.

Thank you!

Comment: Okay, now I think I'm confused about the meaning of this definition. I was thinking the sequence was plugged in as the variable, is it not?

Comment: Another example would be $s_0=1$ and $f(s)=1$.  Thus, $s_1=f(s_0)=1$, $s_2=f(s_1)=1$, and so on, so that $s_n=f(s_{n-1})=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example if $s_0=1$ and $f(x)=2x$, then $s_n=2^n$. 
$$s_0=1\\s_1=f(s_0)=2s_0=2\cdot1=2\\s_2=f(s_1)=2\cdot2=4\\
s_3=f(s_2)=2\cdot4=8.$$

And so on.

Comment: Could you expand this to a few more terms? I'm a little confused about the notation. Thanks for taking the time to respond by the way!

Comment: Sure. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Perfect, it makes sense. Now I know what it means! Thank you! Basically you can choose any function, like Andre Nicolas stated earlier, and define it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following two surprising examples:

> Let $f(x)=\sqrt{2x}$ and $S_0=\sqrt{2}.$
>   Then $S_n=\sqrt{2S_{n-1}},\,\,\,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$
>   Note that $\{S_n\}=\left\{\sqrt2, \sqrt{2\sqrt2}, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt2}}, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt2}}},\cdots\right\}$ is a sequence of irrational numbers.
>   But $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ is a rational number.

Also let

> $f(x)=\dfrac12\left(x+\dfrac{2}{x}\right)$ and $S_0=1.$
>   Then $S_n=\dfrac12\left(S_{n-1}+\dfrac{2}{S_{n-1}}\right),\,\,\,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and
>   $\{S_n\}=\left\{1,\dfrac32, \dfrac{17}{12}, \dfrac{577}{408}, \cdots\right\}$ is a sequence of rational numbers.
>   But $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ is an irrational number.